# sklearnを使うと、cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL' というエラーになる

Tags: python, numpy

pythonであるパッケージをインポートして使うと同じようなエラーがでます・
numpyとscikitlearnとpandasなどでます。
コード自体エラーは表示されませんが、コンソールに下記のエラーがでます。
なにがいけないのでしょうか？
matplotlibなどは普通に使えます

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pleiades\workspace\ana\aaa.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl

Answer (score 2):

mklありのnumpyをインストールする必要があるのではないでしょうか

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy